# PostgreSQL equivalent of mysqld --bootstrap or mysqld --init-file

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to automate initializing a postgresql data directory, with a user and a default database pre-created. I know I can do this by running postgresql backgrounded and using `createdb` and `createuser` commands, but I really want to avoid that as this is for a docker container and I just want postgres to be running in the foreground once done.

In MySQL I use `--init-file /path/to/bootstrap.sql`, which runs the statements in the file before the server accepts connections. You can also use `--bootstrap`, which temporarily spins up mysqld and runs statements from STDIN.

I can't find an equally straightforward way to do this in Postgres. I can see a `--boot` option to `postgres`, but when I try and use it I just get "invalid command line arguments", so I must be doing something wrong.

```
echo "CREATE USER bob WITH PASSWORD 'secure';" | postgres --boot postgres -D data
postgres: invalid command-line arguments
```

Comment: What does it mean "postgres to be running in the foreground"?

Comment: I mean what happens when you run `postgres -D /path/to/data/dir`. It sits in the foreground, which is exactly what Docker containers need to do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want the single user mode: `--single`, as described in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postgres.html):

> When invoked in single-user mode from the shell, the user can enter
>   queries and the results will be printed to the screen, but in a form
>   that is more useful for developers than end users. In the single-user
>   mode, the session user will be set to the user with ID 1, and implicit
>   superuser powers are granted to this user. This user does not actually
>   have to exist, so the single-user mode can be used to manually recover
>   from certain kinds of accidental damage to the system catalogs

Note that `initdb` has be run to initialize an empty data directory before creating databases or users. That would be the equivalent of `mysql_install_db` if you prefer to look at  this from the MySQL analogy angle.

Comment: Ah, that does seem to do what I need, thanks! I somehow mis-interpreted that documentation as if it kept postgresql running in a very insecure mode, so I'd have to shut it down. If you cat a file into postgres in that mode, it does the right thing!